Usage of the て form + passive in this sentence
The context is the following: the character recently made a suggestion in order to help his friend. However another character warms him that his "suggestion" may be taken wrongly by his friend.
（勘違いされた…？）
心臓が締め付けられるような息苦しさがある。もしかして、意図がしっかりと伝わっていないのではないか？
むしろ間違って把握されている可能性だってある。
「…っ」目の前が黒くなっていく気がした。自分が思うより動揺しているのだろう
I generally understand the sentence, however I'm stumbled on this part here
むしろ間違って把握されている可能性だってある。
my understanding of this from context is akin to "He may have misunderstood me" however as far I know "把握されている" means "I'm being understood" which obviously doesn't fit the context.
What exactly did I miss in this sentence?

The subject of 把握されている is 意図. "There's even a possibility that the intention is being incorrectly interpreted."

I agree that 把握されている means "being understood". 間違って is the "manner" in which this happens. So you could translate 間違って把握されている as "being understood incorrectly".
"Manner" is one of the ways the te-form is used. Some similar examples:

歩いて帰る (go home on foot)
急いで仕上げる (finish quickly)

